# Strange behaviour in google earth

Tags: python, 3d, direct3d, google-earth, spherical-coordinate

I searched this over the internet and found no explanation. Dragging mouse in a circle makes google earth change orientation with respect the the center of the circle. You can actually control which direction to rotate the earth, by moving the mouse clockwise or anticlockwise. Why this happening? Is this a feature or a bug?

Video of this happening: (https://youtu.be/vQZafuDO1VU)

[image: Gif]

This also works with any other 3D viewing softwares.

Dragging the mouse in a circle should not do anything other than wobbling the 3d object along the same direction. But it actually results in an additional rotation in the direction of circling. I suspect this has to something do with the algo used for the spherical coordinates mouse interaction.